# How can I fetch all images from single child and show them with viewflipper

Tags: android, slider, viewflipper

please help me solving my problem. I want to make images swipable left to right or right to left in an ImageView so it look like a slider but not auto start, if swipe next image will ippear in the same view. please see my database structure as image attachment. I want same database structure as shown in attachment.

[Please see the database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tsS8f.jpg)

Comment: Maybe you want to use `ViewPager`?

Comment: Ok I its fine to me but can I use data structure same as my attachment, I mean all images from only one child

Comment: Create a `List` of images on your Database and that is it. You can then obtain them in `List<String> urls` in your app.

Comment: actually I am new and could not find a better and easy solution.... If you don't mind can you give me full code seeing my database structure above

Answer (score 0):

Use [ViewPager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager) for image slider.

Overview of ViewPager: 
It contain PagerAdapter (just like Recyclerview Adapter) to all child fragments. You can use ImageView in Fragment  to show images.

Reference links:

https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide

https://www.journaldev.com/10096/android-viewpager-example-tutorial